# ASP Menu Item not working in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, asp.net, mobile, menuitem

My asp menu items won't display on mobile devices, even when I click them. Is there a way to display the menu items when click on mobile?

EDIT:

My code works on desktop when hovered, but in mobile you cannot hover of course, so, how can it work when clicked or should I say tap on the phone?

Here is my code:

```
        <asp:Menu  RenderingMode="Table" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" CssClass="MyMenu1" ID="Menu1" Orientation="Horizontal" runat="server">
            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="Menu" VerticalPadding="10" HorizontalPadding="5" />
            <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="MenuHover" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="MenuItem" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="MenuHoverDynamic" />
            <Items>

                <asp:MenuItem   PopOutImageUrl="~/Images/ICONS/expand-button.png" ImageUrl="~/Images/ICONS/transactions.png" Text="<br>Transactions" Value="Transactions">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="../info/patientinfo.aspx" Text="Patient Info" Value="Patient Info"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="../FINANCIAL/CashAssessment.aspx"  Text="Cash Assessment" Value="Cash Assessment"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="../MEDICAL/DocRx.aspx"  Text="Pharmacy Request" Value="Pharmacy Request"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="../MEDICAL/ProcedureRequestT.aspx"   Text="Procedure Request" Value="Procedure Request"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>

            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: The asp code doesn't matters, we need the generatetd html code + css.

Comment: I've edited my question @AndyTschiersch